# Dummy function decorator with arguments

Tags: python, wrapper

I am trying to write a dummy wrapper in the case where some module is not installed.
I have found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904486/python-wrapper-function-taking-arguments-inside-decorator):

```py
from functools import wraps

def jit(*args0, **kwargs0):
    def outer(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return inner
    return outer
```

but I would like the wrapper to be as lightweight as possible (even if functools is standard, it is too much just for doing nothing), and to accept multiple parameters:

```py
@jit(nopython=True)
def myFunction(*args, **kwargs):
    return None
```

i have tried something like this :

```py
def jit(func, nopython, **kwargs2):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner
```

But I get this exception :

```py
TypeError: jit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'
```

Is there a standard way to create a simple wrapper like this?

Answer (score 0):

Answer based on [meta-decorators](https://hangar.runway7.net/python/decorators-and-wrappers):

```py
def jit(*args0, **kwargs0):
    def wrapper(func):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return inner
    return wrapper
```

The first code snippet was entirely valid, and the functools.wrap method not needed.