# How to you get the information that a wrapper function returns when using a decorator function in Python?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am trying to access the time to execute a function that is inside a decorator function.

I followed the direction in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904486/python-wrapper-function-taking-arguments-inside-decorator) because I was unable to get the function to take the arguments I passed to it. Now I am unsure of how to get the data from calling the function.

Here is my code:

```py
import time
from functools import wraps

def sort_timer(func):
    def outer(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            start = time.perf_counter()
            func(*args, **kwargs)
            finish = time.perf_counter()
            return start - finish
        return inner
    return outer

@sort_timer
def bubble_sort(a_list):
    """Sorts a_list in ascending order"""
    for pass_num in range(len(a_list) - 1):
        for index in range(len(a_list) - 1 - pass_num):
            if a_list[index] > a_list[index + 1]:
                temp = a_list[index]
                a_list[index] = a_list[index + 1]
                a_list[index + 1] = temp

list1 = [60, 19, 22, 14, 43, 27, 3, 77]
x = bubble_sort(list1)
print(x)
```

It would appear that what is being returned is the inner function. Here is what is logged to the console:

```
<function sort_timer.<locals>.outer.<locals>.inner at 0x0000027167770310>
```

Any insight would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: To clarify. I am trying to access the data from ***start - finish***.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Where do you use `sort_timer`?

Comment: Thank you! I use sort timer above the definition of the function as @sort_timer

Comment: Could you show us that code?

Comment: Sure. I will edit it into the question.

Answer (score 2):

The code in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30904603/12975140) to which you refer is specifically for supplying arguments to the decorator. It will work as long as you put `()` after `@sort_timer`... and, as currently written, provide an argument. Here's an example, with the first `func` parameter renamed for clarity:

```
def sort_timer(parameter):
    def outer(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            start = time.perf_counter()
            func(*args, **kwargs)
            finish = time.perf_counter()
            return start - finish
        return inner
    return outer

@sort_timer(13) # for example
...
```

That said, in your code as shown, you're not really using the double-wrapper technique to any advantage. Unless you plan on supplying arguments to the decorator itself (not the decorated function), you could simplify like so:

```
def sort_timer(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.perf_counter()
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        finish = time.perf_counter()
        return start - finish
    return inner
```

Comment: Okay. I think I understand. So, if I were to use that technique I can supply arguments to the decorator function itself to use in the outer function.

Comment: Yes, exactly. You would supply them to the decorator, so instead of `@sort_timer`, you could do something like `@sort_timer('seconds')` (just as an example).

Comment: @CrazyChucky Linked answer is correct, it's just that the intended usage is for the decorator be passed arguments. Even though there aren't any in this case, `@sort_timer()` can be used. You can see that the example decorator has arguments provided in the linked answer.

Comment: @SuperStormer Thank you! I messed up and completely forgot how the semantics of defining argument-accepting decorators work; I had it in my head that the decorated function was just one of the arguments it accepted. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using a simple decorator for timing like e.g. mentioned in [timeit versus timing decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622943/timeit-versus-timing-decorator) ?

```
import time
import functools

def timeit(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def timed(*args, **kw):

        ts = time.time()
        result = f(*args, **kw)
        te = time.time()

        print(f"func:{f.__name__} args:{args}{'' if len(kw) == 0 else kw} took: {(te-ts)*1000 :.3f} msec")
        return result

    return timed

@timeit
def bubble_sort(a_list):
    """Sorts a_list in ascending order"""
    for pass_num in range(len(a_list) - 1):
        for index in range(len(a_list) - 1 - pass_num):
            if a_list[index] > a_list[index + 1]:
                temp = a_list[index]
                a_list[index] = a_list[index + 1]
                a_list[index + 1] = temp

list1 = [60, 19, 22, 14, 43, 27, 3, 77]
x = bubble_sort(list1)
```

which prints:

```
func:bubble_sort args:([3, 14, 19, 22, 27, 43, 60, 77],) took: 0.029 msec
```

The `@functools.wraps(f)` takes `f`'s meta information and copies it to the decorating function `timed`, so that the resulting decorated function keeps the features of the original/target function.

Comment: Hello Gwang-Jin Kim. This is the implementation this is the implementation that I wound up using. I am very new to decorators, and I was a little unsure of how to implement them. So, I was looking for how to use the decorators. That's why the version I put in my question was more complicated.

Comment: @TypeError A Decorator in python is nothing than a function which takes another function and uses/calls it in a new function it defines inside its definition - and the newly defined function - which uses/calls the other function - is returned at the end of the decorator definition. So it defines a function which in turn calls the target function. But before or after it calls the other function, you can add a myriad of other stuff it does in addition besides calling the other function. So the decorator adds additional functionality to a simple function call. Thus it 'decorates'.

Comment: @TypeError I was looking about the `@functools.wraps` decorator - it copies some metainformation of the decorated function to the decorating function. So I will add it to the decorator.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code for calculating execute time of a function:

```
import time
 
def timer(func):
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    start = time.time()
    func(*args, **kwargs)
    end = time.time() - start
    print(end)
  return wrapper
```