# Python decorator with a function that receives a parameter

Tags: python, function, parameters, decorator

Decorator is not working as intended

I was trying to understand more about decorators, so I searched and got many videos that made this exact function:

```
def tictoc(func):
    def wrapper():
        t1 = time.time()
        return func()
        t2 = time.time()-t1
        print(f'Took {t2} seconds to run.')
    return wrapper
```

So I made a factorial function, that takes a parameter (the number you want to see the factorial)

```
@tictoc
def fat(num):
    f = 1
    for x in range(1, num+1):
        f *= x
    return f

print(fat(5))
```

and then I ran it

but I got this error: TypeError: tictoc..wrapper() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Someone can please explain me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome.. No images please......... Copy paste the code.

Comment: You can see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) why.

Comment: code after `return func()` will never run. I'm surprised any source would give you that wrapper example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python wrapper function taking arguments inside decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904486/python-wrapper-function-taking-arguments-inside-decorator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem #1: The decorator does not allow passing of the argument as you are calling your func at return without arguments

```py
def tictoc(func):
    def wrapper():
        t1 = time.time()
        return func() #<—- here is the 
        t2 = time.time()-t1
        print(f'Took {t2} seconds to run.')
    return wrapper
```

We can correct that:

```py
def tictoc(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        t1 = time.time()
        return func(*args, **kwargs) 
        t2 = time.time()-t1 # <— this will not be evaluated as we have returned 
        print(f'Took {t2} seconds to run.') # <- this too
    return wrapper
```

Problem #2: Return statement will return. t2 and print as pointed in the comment above will not be evaluated. We can fix that:

```py
def tictoc(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        t1 = time.time()
        results = func(*args, **kwargs) 
        t2 = time.time()-t1 
        print(f'Took {t2} seconds to run.')
        return results 
    return wrapper
```

This should work now. We can add one last tweak to preserve the name of our function

As it is, the decorator will change the name of your function.

```py
@tictoc
def fat(num):
    f = 1
    for x in range(1, num+1):
        f *= x
    return f

print(fat.__name__)
#outputs wrapper
```

To fix that

```py
from functools import wraps


def tictoc(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        t1 = time.time()
        results = func(*args, **kwargs) 
        t2 = time.time()-t1 
        print(f'Took {t2} seconds to run.')
        return results 
    return wrapper
```

The output of `print(fat.__name__)` is not correct `fat`.

Another way to write your decorator could be using a class which is easier to read.

```py
class tictoc:

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.__name__ = func.__name__

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        t1 = time.time()

        results = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        t2 = time.time() - t1
        print(f'Took {t2} seconds to run.')
        return results
```

This should work as above but gives less freedom. For example adding parameters to your decorator. With function we can do that with three nested functions

```py
def tictoc(loops=1):
    def inner(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            
            t2_ = 0
            for loop in range(1, loops+1):
                print(f'{loop=}')
                t1 = time.time()
                results = func(*args, **kwargs)
                t2 = time.time() - t1
                t2_ += t2
                
                print(f'Took {t2} seconds to run')
            if loops > 1:
                print(f'Took average {t2_/loops} seconds to run')
                
            return results
    
        return wrapper
    return inner




@tictoc(3)
def fat(num):
    f = 1
    for x in range(1, num + 1):
        f *= x
    return f

print(fat(5))
```

Still pondering how to do it with class ;)

Comment: Initially your answer looked identical to mine that I had posted earlier. Eventually you are adding very interesting material. Kudos.

Comment: I did not see yours :( I would have edited yours is instead.

Answer (score 0):

As JonSG has noted, the return statement produces to skip the rest of the code after it, so that t2 is never evaluated and the print is not executed.

You might want to rewrite your code like this:

```
import time

def tictoc(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        t1 = time.time()
        _func = func(*args, **kwargs)
        t2 = time.time()-t1
        print(f'Took {t2} seconds to run.')
        return _func
    return wrapper

@tictoc
def fac(num):
    f = 1
    for x in range(1, num+1):
        f *= x
    return f

print(fac(3))
```

First of all, you need to pass arguments to the decorator. You do this by using `*args` and `**kwargs` in the inner wrapper function (perhaps here `**kwargs` is superfluous). The inner wrapper then passes these to the wrapped function. Second, you store the result of your function into `_func` and return it after you evaluate t2.